# using USART in STM32L4R5

Tags: stm32

I am using asynchronous `USART` on `STM32L4R5` for communication with PC. I am able to receive data on PC side but I am not able to receive any data on nucleo board send by PC. Following is the code I am using for transmission

```
while (1)
{
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port,LD2_Pin); //Toggle LED
  HAL_Delay(1000);
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      USART1->TDR = p[i];
      while((USART1->ISR  & 0x40) == 0);
  }
  while ((USART1->ISR & 0x20) == 0);
  uint32_t receivedByte = (uint32_t)(USART1->RDR);
}
```

In the above sending part is working fine but receiving is not working. I have checked and wiring is proper.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it crash? Does it fail to compile?

Comment: As I have mentioned above I am able to send data to PC but not able to receive data on nucleo board. It's not crashing and I am able to compile it also. I am just not receiving data on nucelo board send by PC.

Comment: What happens then? Is it stuck at `while ((USART1->ISR & 0x20) == 0);`? If not, how to do you know it's not receiving data? The variable `receivedByte` goes out of scope immediately and is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just using USART Receiving interrupt it will help you in capturing received data. Rather than polling for USART Reception. 
There are two reasons for no response

1. You might not sending EOD and Carriage return while sending data on USART. Many USART based operation based on these character. Module will listen to USART untill these characters are received.
2. Your hardware connections are not right. Make sure you are connecting TX to Host to Rx of Slave and vice versa.

I suggest USART interrupt because polling is not a good method while writing a code.

Comment: Your response is in the gray area between comment and answer. I understand you have insufficient reputation to comment. Can you describe your idea better (e.g. with a code sample)? That would make it a proper answer.